# tabdivider not working on FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments

fragmenttabhost.xml is

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:showDividers="middle"
            android:divider="@drawable/tab_divider"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

and **tab_divider.xml** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <size
        android:height="100px"
        android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/red" />
</shape>
```

any help will be highly appreciable. 
Thanks.

Comment: you are checking on ics?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicity add the separater in this manner

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView dividerImage = new ImageView(this);
        dividerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab_seperator);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Page1.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("page1").setIndicator(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab1, null))
                  .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.getTabWidget().addView(dividerImage, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Page2.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("page2").setIndicator(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab2, null))
                  .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
```